# Update SQL Date to ISO Format

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net-mvc, date

I have an issue with Date Format.
Before, I was using MVC .Net format to send Date from DB to javascript as this :

```
'\/Date(1111111111)\/'.jsonToDate()
```

Now I'm using JSON.Net and I send a ISOFormatted Date to javascript as this :

```
new Date('2014-03-24T07:00:00+01:00')
```

But now I have an offset of 1 hours (Paris time).

What is the best way to resolve this problem ?

- Update SQL date to remove 1 hours
- Add ISO Time to SQL Date (how ?)?
- Remove 1 hours when sending date to javascript ?
- Remove +01:00 ?

Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about converting to UTC and back to ISO sting?

```
var utcStr=new Date('2014-03-24T07:00:00+01:00').toUTCString();
new Date(Date.parse(utcStr)).toISOString() //2014-03-24T06:00:00.000Z
```

Check out <kbd>[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)</kbd>

There are some built in library like [**Moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/) for Date manipulation

Comment: @User.Anonymous, added some library link. check it, will be helpful

Comment: That works with your solution, thank you. For the library, it is scheduled since some teammates use it on another project and it works great. But no time on my project to implement it now :/